# shuffle string values in PHP

Tags: php

I want to shuffle the string values instead from an array. I was replacing the text in my code where options are strings. Is it possible to shuffle string values

Shuffle the string values.

```
   $shufflevar = 'question: "'.$question.'", 
                  answers: ["'.$correctanswer.'", "'.$option1.'", "'.$option2.'", "'.$option3.'"]
                 ';
```

Tried with shuffle function:

```
   $shufflevar = 'question: "'.$question.'", 
                  answers: ['.shuffle ($correctanswer, $option1, $option2, $option3).']
                 ';
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Can you share more details? Why not use an array as the input to `shuffle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$shuffleArray=[$correctanswer, $option1, $option2, $option3];

shuffle($shuffleArray);
 

$shuffleString=implode("",$shuffleArray);
```

Comment: Shuffle does not accept values being put directly into it. It needs to be given a pre-formed array.

Comment: `shuffle` returns a `bool`, not the array itself.

Comment: that implode as is, is going to mash all the options together (i'd change `""` to `", "`)

Answer (score 1):

[Shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) accepts an array, you are passing it multiple string values. So to shuffle your options with the answer, store all of them into an array first and pass that array to shuffle.

```php
$potentialAnswers = [
   $correctanswer,
   $option1,
   $option2,
   $option3
];
shuffle($potentialAnswers);
$shufflevar = 'question: "'. $question .'", 
               answers: ["' . implode(', ', $potentialAnswers) . '"]
';
```

Note that the shuffle method accepts the array passed by reference, and returns a boolean indicating success or failure (as opposed to returning the shuffled array).

Answer (score 0):

[`shuffle` shuffles an array in-place](https://www.php.net/shuffle), meaning that it takes the argument and randomizes the sequence of contents in it. Add your options to an array, shuffle that array and then you'll have the results you're looking for:

```
$correctanswer = 'foo'; $option1 = 'bar'; $option2 = 'baz'; $option3 = 'spam';
$options = [$correctanswer, $option1, $option2, $option3];
shuffle($options);
var_dump($options);
```

You can also join all the options together with a separator by using `join`:

```
join(', ', $options)
```

But it seems like you're trying to output JSON manually - in that case, use `json_encode` directly instead.

Comment: Seems to be close to JSON but not quite. The keys are not quoted and the values inside array are not either (unless the variables themselves contain that.